# mocking database objects with Rhino mock

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, testing, rhino-mocks, rhino

I am sorry if this question is already been asked. I am very new to Unit Testing and I am suppose to use Rhino for mocking.

So the problem is...I have a method to test and that method is suppose to do retrive some data based on input parameter and return as datatable.

It also do some calculation for finding out which stored procedure should be called and with which set of parameters.

I issue is that, When I call the method with mock objects....it throws an error at date from database retrival line of code as object is not set to an instanse. That is expected as their is no data retruning from database since we are mocking it.

so what could be done it that case.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is a good time to introduce [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).

If you introduce than, the logic to generate query to DB and the logic to read data from DB will be encapsulated in the Repository.

In this case you can mock/stub the Repository in your tests and you can unit test all the classes, which use Repository, without creation test DB at all.

The Repository mock will verify whether incoming parameters are correct.
And the Repository stub will return any test-specific data which you need for each particular test.